# Injetar resultados e a paginação dentro de um html

Tags: php, html

Tenho duas páginas feitas em html uma chamada index.html onde o usuario digita um nome de uma produto (ex: Lapis) e o resultado é exibido em uma pagina diferente e como o resultado da consulta pode ser muito grande dependendo da consulta deverá haver uma paginação de resultados.
O Problema em questão é que não consigo colocar resultado da consulta dentro da pagina de exibição tampouco criar uma paginação adequada.

Codigo index.html responsavel pela inserção do termo a ser consultado:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ValidateForm.php" method="get">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="result_type" value="produtos" checked=""/>Produtos</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="search_input" name="search_input" placeholder="Search"/>
        <button type="submit" name="search_form_submit" value="Search">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Código exibir.html onde deveria ser exibidos os resultados paginados da consulta:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Exibe produtos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:red">
        <div id="conteudo" style="background-color:yellow;width:400px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer id="paginacao">
    </footer>
</body>
```

Código ValidateForm.php responsavel por tratar o formulario enviado na index.html e mandar os termos já validados para o .php resposavel pela consulta.

```
<?php
include_once "QueryInDB.php";

class ValidadeForm{
    static function validate(){
        if(isset($_GET['search_form_submit'])){
            ValidadeForm::validateSearch();
        }
    }

    static function validateSearch(){
        $erro = false;

        if(!isset($_GET) || empty($_GET)){
            $erro = 'Nada foi postado.';
        }

        $values = array();
        foreach($_GET as $chave => $valor){
            // Remove todas as tags HTML
            $values[$chave] = strip_tags($valor);

            // Verifica se tem algum valor nulo
            if(empty($valor)){
                $erro = 'Existem campos em branco.';
            }
        }

        if(!isset($values['search_input']) && !$erro){
            $erro = 'Consulta Nula';
        }

        if($erro){
            echo $erro;
        }else{
            array_pop($values);//Tira o nome do Button submit
            print_r(queryInDB::search($values));
        }
    }   
}

ValidadeForm::validate();
?>
```

Código QueryInDB.php código responsavel pela realização da consulta e retornar o resultado à ValidadeForm (que em tese deveria fazer a inserção dos resultados dentro da exibir.html)

```
<?php
class queryInDB{
    static function search($values){
        $conn = queryInDB::openConnection();
        $stmt = queryInDB::queryFactory($conn,$values);
        $result = queryInDB::queryExecute($stmt);
        return $result;
    }

    static function openConnection(){
        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=loja", 'teste', 'teste');
            return $conn;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        }
    }

    static function queryFactory($conn,$values){
        $colunm = $values['result_type'];
        array_shift($values);//Tira o Seletor Radio Button ()
        $values = (string)$values['search_input'];//Pega o input do usuario e transforma em string
        $values = explode(' ',$values);
        $keywords = array();
        foreach($values as $value){
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $value = '%' . $value . '%';
            $keywords[] = $value;
        }           
        $keys = 'nome LIKE ' . str_repeat('? OR nome LIKE ', count($keywords) - 1) . '?';
        $stmt['stmt'] = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, nome, descricao, valor FROM ' . $colunm . ' WHERE ' . $keys);
        $stmt['params'] = $keywords;
        return $stmt;
    }

    static function queryExecute($stmt){
        $stmt['stmt']->execute($stmt['params']);
        $result = $stmt['stmt']->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Não consegui fazer a injeção dos resultados dentro da exibir.html e nem injetar a paginação adequada, é importante não inserir código php dentro da exibir.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de paginação que envolve uma busca no banco de dados:

```
<?php
    //conexão com o banco de dados
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("banco_teste" );

    //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página
        $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    //seleciona todos os itens da tabela
        $cmd = "select * from produtos";
        $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);

    //conta o total de itens
        $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);

    //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens
        $registros = 2;

    //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
        $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

    //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
        $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros;

    //seleciona os itens por página
        $cmd = "select * from produtos limit $inicio,$registros";
        $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
        $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);

    //exibe os produtos selecionados
        while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {
            echo $produto['id']." - ";
            echo $produto['nome']." - ";
            echo $produto['descricao']." - ";
            echo "R$ ".$produto['valor']."<br />";
        }

    //exibe a paginação
    if($pagina > 1) {
        echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".($pagina - 1)."' class='controle'>&laquo; anterior</a>";
    }

    for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) {
        $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? 'numativo' : '';
        echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".$i."' class='numero ".$ativo."'> ".$i." </a>";
    }

    if($pagina < $numPaginas) {
        echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".($pagina + 1)."' class='controle'>proximo &raquo;</a>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente acredito que não seja possível você inserir os resultados sem colocar código `PHP` em `exibir.html`, já que esses resultados são recuperados de forma dinâmica do banco de dados.

Com relação à paginação, eu sugiro que você utilize as facilidades que o banco de dados oferece usando a função limit por exemplo. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging)